# Returning different return value

Tags: java

When i have a problem with the code im writing, i usually handle it like a story. Each command is a sentence in a story. The sentences needs to make sense in order for the story to be complete/right.

So im learning java from scratch now with the MOOC course at Helsinki University. I got somewhat stuck at exercise 68. The program is suppose to compare integer values of a list(array) together with user input. What i programmed is a method that return true if the user input number is already on the list, and false if its not.

What I said about story at the start: The commented out code is my initial code. This did not past the last test but in my head both the commented out code and the other code say basically the same

**Error message (from last test):**
*"Answer wrong when parameter was list [0, 7, 9, -1, 13, 8, -1] and value 8 expected: **false** but was: **true**"*

```
public static boolean moreThanOnce(ArrayList<Integer> list, int searched) 
//        if (list.size()==1) {return false;}
//        
//        for (int i = 0; i < list.size();i++  ){
//          if (list.contains(searched)) 
//          
//          {
//          
//              return true; }
//          
//        }
//return false;
//   
        int counter = 0;
        for (int num : list) {
            if (searched == num) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (counter >= 2){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I understand that there is something wrong, just cant seem to figure it out. Do you see why the last code would be accepted, but not the first (commented out one) ?

If any use, the rest of the code (not my work) is this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(3);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(2);

        System.out.println("Type a number: ");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        if (moreThanOnce(list, number)) {
            System.out.println(number + " appears more than once.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(number + " does not appear more than once. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return true` instantly returns from the function. `list.contains` returns true when there's at least **one** matching element in the list, not more than one. Therefore, your first version just checked if the element appeared in the list at all, not if it appeared more than once. Note that the loop is redundant, as `list.contains` searches the entire list for you anyway.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem. It's not to find if the number is already in the list. It's to find if appears multiple times in the list.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Also note that the second method keeps counting, for nothing, after the counter reaches the value 2.

Answer (score 0):

Code that is commented out guaranties only that if true there is at least one of occurance in array, maybe there are more but not guaranted. If function returns false thes may be 1 or no occurance.

Reason: If arrary os bigger than 1 it does not mean that there are 2 or more occurances of value you search for.

Posible solution: Add counter like uncommented code.

Answer (score 0):

Your first algorithm has a few flaws, first you test for a length of one explicitly. Not `null`, and not an empty `List`. Second, you should prefer the `List` interface to the `ArrayList` explicit type. And finally, you need to consider the **sublist** offset by one of the current position when you call contains (clearly the list contains *at least* the current value).

I think you wanted something like

```
public static boolean moreThanOnce(List<Integer> list, int searched) {
    if (list == null || list.size() < 2) {
        return false;
    }

    int len = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals(searched) 
                    && list.subList(i + 1, list.size()).contains(searched)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**And**, we can express that as *generic* method. Like,

```
public static <T> boolean moreThanOnce(List<T> list, T searched) {
    if (list == null || list.size() < 2) {
        return false;
    }

    int len = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals(searched) 
                    && list.subList(i + 1, list.size()).contains(searched)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**or**, if you're using Java 8+, use a `Stream` and `filter` and then `count` like

```
public static <T> boolean moreThanOnce(List<T> list, T searched) {
    if (list == null || list.size() < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    return list.stream().filter(v -> v.equals(searched)).count() > 1;
}
```